# The "stubborn" solutions to sums of three cubes

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

It is conjectured (see [[1](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-59-200/S0025-5718-1992-1146835-5/home.html)]) that for any integer $k\not\equiv \pm 4\pmod 9$ there are infinitely many integer solutions to
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3=k.
$$
Numerical investigations of this conjecture show that for some $k$ solutions are easily found (for example, $510=101^3-100^3-31^3$), while other $k$ kind of "resist" the numerical search. Notable example is
$$
(−80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3=42
$$
found by A. Booker and A. Sutherland in 2019. But is this phenomenon known to exist for infinitely many $k$? More precisely, let
$$
s(k)=\min_{a^3+b^3+c^3=k}\max\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}.
$$
and $S(x)=\max\limits_{\substack{k\leq x\\ k\not\equiv \pm 4\pmod 9}} s(k)$. Obviously, we don't even know if $S(114)$ is finite, so there is no upper bound for $S$ known. But what can be said about *lower* bounds for $S(x)$ for large $x$? Obviously, $S(x)\gg x^{1/3}$. Is it at least true that
$$
\limsup_{x\to +\infty} \frac{S(x)}{x^{1/3}}=+\infty?
$$
I think that a solid case for existence of "stubborn" integers would be a bound of the form $S(x)\gg x^{f(x)}$ with $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$ or at least $S(x)\gg x^A$ for some large $A$ (like $A=100$, for example), but I don't know if anything like this is within the reach of current techniques or even likely to be true.

Comment: You might be able to deduce the ratio going to infinity bit by choosing a $k$ that is a cubic non-residue for the first several primes that are $1 \mod 3$.   I think then the constants in Heath-Brown's conjectured asymptotic would be small, and then a counting argument along such values of $k$ might do the job.  Of course I haven't done the work.

Comment: I always get nervous with anonymous references like [1], in case of link rot.  The referenced paper is [Heath-Brown - The density of zeros of forms for which weak approximation fails](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-59-200/S0025-5718-1992-1146835-5).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This lim sup indeed goes to $\infty$. We can prove this using exactly the strategy Lucia suggested.

We will count the number of $x,y,z$ in a box with $x^3+y^3+z^3$ not a cubic residue modulo $p$ for a large finite list of primes $p$, all congruent to $1$ mod $3$. We can similarly count the number of $n$ not a cubic residue modulo $p$ for the same finite list of primes. From the pigeonhole principle, we can deduce that some $n$ is not a cubic residue for any $x,y,z$ in the box.

For $p$ congruent to $1$ mod $3$, the number of solutions of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3=0 $ in $\mathbb F_p$ is $$ p^3 + 6 p^2-6p $$ and the number of solutions to $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$ is $$1 + (p-1 ) (p - a_p + 1) = p^2 - a_p (p-1) $$ where $|a_p| < 2 \sqrt{p}$ so the number of $x,y,z\in \mathbb F_p$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is a perfect cube is $$ \frac{ p^3 + 6 p^2 -6p + 2 (  p^2 - a_p (p-1) )}{3} $$ and thus the number of $x,y,z$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is not a perfect cube is

$$ p^3 - \frac{ p^3 + 6 p^2 -6p + 2 (  p^2 - a_p (p-1) )}{3} = \frac{ 2 p^3 - 8 p^2 - 2 a_p (p-1)}{3} .$$

Now let $c>0$ be an integer, and assume that $n>0$ is divisible by $\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^3$. Then the number of $x,y,z$ with $|x|, |y|, |z| < c n^{1/3} $ such that $x^3+y^3 + z^3$ is not a perfect cube mod any of $p_1,\dots p_k$ is

$$8 c^3 n \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{ 2 p_i^3 - 8 p_i^2 - 2 a_{p_i}  (p_i-1) + 6p_i }{3p_i^3},$$

while the number of numbers less then $n$ that are not perfect cubes mod any of the $p_1,\dotsc, p_k$ is

$$ 2 n \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{ 2 (p_i-1)}{ 3 p_i }, $$

Therefore, by the pigeonhole principle, there must be some number $<n$ with no solutions with $|x|,|y|,|z| < cn^{1/3}$ as soon as

$$  8 c^3 n \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{ 2 p_i^3 - 8 p_i^2 - 2 a_{p_i}  (p_i-1) +6p_i}{3p_i^3}<  2 n \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{ 2 (p-1)}{ 3 p },$$ which happens when

$$ 4 c^3 < \prod_{i=1}^k  \frac{ p_i^2 (p_i-1) }{  p_i^3 - 4 p_i^2 -  a_{p_i}  (p_i-1) + 3p_i} .$$

To check that we can take the integer $c>0$ sufficiently large, which lets the lim sup go to $\infty$, we need only ensure that the product goes to $\infty$ as the list $p_1,\dotsc, p_k$ grows to include all primes congruent to $1$ mod $3$. This is not hard to do as each factor is approximately $\frac{1}{ (1-p_i^{-1})^3}$ and the divergence follows from the fact that the primes congruent to $1$ mod $3$ have Dirichlet density $1/2 > 0$.

If we take $p_1,\dots, p_k$ the $k$ smallest primes congruent to $1$ mod $3$, and $n^{1/3}$ to be $\prod_{i=1}^k p_i$, I believe this method gives a lower bound like $\limsup_{ x\to\infty}  \frac{S(x)}{ x^{1/3} \sqrt{ \log \log x }} >0$.

Comment: One can improve on this, maybe to $x^{1/3} e^{ \sqrt{ \log \log x}}$, by counting only points in a region like $|x|,|y|,|z|<m$, $|x^3+y^3+z^3|<n$.

Comment: Excellent!  My one nitpick is that "pigeon" doesn't have a d in it.

Comment: Why $n$ not a cube modulo many such primes $p$? I can see that $n=3\mod 7$ entails $x^3=y^3=z^3=1\mod 7$, but more possibilities exist for $(x, y, z)$ if $n=2\mod 7$; and I don't see how $n$ not being a cube mod $p$ suggests $n$ is stubborn if $p>7$. How are the primes weighted? I tried weighting $p$ by $1/p$; using the 3014 primes $p\le59971$ with $p=1\mod 6$, those $n<999$ seeming stubborn include 17, 205 and 982. Elsenhans and Jahnel's list of solutions suggest that they aren't all that stubborn. Perhaps a different weighting is better?

Comment: It seems to me that there is a typo in your $p^3+6p^2$ formula? Shouldn't the answer be $1 \bmod p-1$, since this is a homogenous equation? I think the right answer is $p^3+6p^2-6p$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, good point, I forgot the $(p-1)$ factor in the Gauss sum terms.

Comment: @RosieF  In fact $n=2 \mod 7$ and $n=3 \mod 7$ have the same number of solutions - there are $27$ $(x,y,z)$ with $x^3=y^3=z^3=1\mod 7$, and also $27$ where two are $1$ and the other is $0$ - the fewer number of choices that cube to $0$ exactly balances the choice of which one cubes to $0$. The correct thing is to multiply the the number of solutions mod $p$ divided by $p^2$ over all primes $p\neq 3$ times the number of solutions mod $9$ divided by $3^4$.

Comment: @RosieF This is explained, and the solutions are counted, in the last two pages of Heath-Brown's paper The Density of Zeros of Forms for which Weak Approximation Fails. The specific densities for small $k$ were probably calculated along with the recent computer search efforts so you could look there. The "fake stubbon" examples you give are congruent to $8, 7,$ and $1$ mod $7$ - probably the fact that they are not congruent to $\pm 3$ mod $9$ is the source of their fallure to be stubborn.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks for catching my mistake re number of solutions modulo 7, and for the Heath-Brown reference.

Comment: I added the condition that $c>0$ is an integer, while I removed the condition that $n>0$ is sufficiently large. The point is that the fifth and sixth displays now hold exactly (not just asymptotically), while this was not true under the old conditions. (The old conditions were also fine, but one would need to tell the story slightly differently to take care of the $o(n)$ errors.)

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks! (And sorry for doing incomplete edits to fix it in a hurry.)